# Resolving BIOS-Related Errors during Ubuntu Installation

Tags: bios, bootloader

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu on my laptop. The laptop originally had Windows installed on an SSD, but the SSD is not working properly, so I want to install Ubuntu on the hard disk instead. During the Ubuntu installation process, I encountered some BIOS-related errors. Eventually, the installation completed successfully, but when I restarted the laptop, the Windows boot menu appeared instead of the Ubuntu boot menu. I checked the boot loader options, but the Ubuntu OS does not appear. Can you help me fix this issue?

Comment: What brand/model laptop? UEFI install? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: https://youtu.be/fleF4qDtwDE Here is the solution